# Getting Different Different DISTINCT result in CakePHP query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, cakephp

**I have accepted the Answer. But welcome for more answers and suggestion.**

I am getting different - different MySQL result when using distinct in CakePHP query.

**What i am trying to do :** Getting **distinct** result of **date_generated** field.

**Problem :**  Query 1 is working fine but when i am getting two fields (date_generated, id ) (see query 2) then **distinct** result not working.

**Query 1**

```
$this->Purchase->find('all',array( 
                               'order' => array('Purchase.date_generated ASC'),
                               'fields' => array('DISTINCT Purchase.date_generated')));
```

**Result with Query 1** : in this result **date_generated** is not repeating and Working fine. Please check Query 2.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Purchase] => Array
                (
                    [date_generated] => 1970-01-01
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Purchase] => Array
                (
                    [date_generated] => 2014-06-17
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [Purchase] => Array
                (
                    [date_generated] => 2014-06-18
                )

        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [Purchase] => Array
                (
                    [date_generated] => 2014-06-19
                )

        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [Purchase] => Array
                (
                    [date_generated] => 2014-06-22
                )

        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [Purchase] => Array
                (
                    [date_generated] => 2014-06-29
                )

        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [Purchase] => Array
                (
                    [date_generated] => 2014-08-01
                )

        )

)
```

**Query 2** : only added 'Purchase.id'

```
$this->Purchase->find('all',array( 
                               'order' => array('Purchase.date_generated ASC'),
                               'fields' => array('DISTINCT Purchase.date_generated','Purchase.id')));
```

**Result of Query 2** : In this result Array index 5,6,7 date_generated repeating.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Purchase] => Array
                (
                    [date_generated] => 1970-01-01
                    [id] => 9
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Purchase] => Array
                (
                    [date_generated] => 2014-06-17
                    [id] => 1
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [Purchase] => Array
                (
                    [date_generated] => 2014-06-18
                    [id] => 2
                )

        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [Purchase] => Array
                (
                    [date_generated] => 2014-06-19
                    [id] => 3
                )

        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [Purchase] => Array
                (
                    [date_generated] => 2014-06-22
                    [id] => 4
                )

        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [Purchase] => Array
                (
                    [date_generated] => 2014-06-29
                    [id] => 5
                )

        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [Purchase] => Array
                (
                    [date_generated] => 2014-06-29
                    [id] => 6
                )

        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [Purchase] => Array
                (
                    [date_generated] => 2014-06-29
                    [id] => 7
                )

        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [Purchase] => Array
                (
                    [date_generated] => 2014-08-01
                    [id] => 8
                )

        )

)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems like standard sql behaviour. First query produces something like this

select
DISTINCT Purchase.date_generated
from
Purchase
order by
Purchase.date_generated ASC

the second one produces query like that

select
DISTINCT Purchase.date_generated,
Purchase.id
from
Purchase
order by
Purchase.date_generated ASC

The results of those queries are exactly what you got. For the socond one it will return distinct pairs of Purchase.date_generated and Purchase.id. So if for some date there is several purchase ids each of them is distinct pair.

So if you are after distinct date only you should use the first query.

Comment: ok thankx . But when i need both date_generated and id then what should i do ?

Comment: It depends on how you would like your output to look like. Could you put sample expected output in your question?

Comment: i think its fine i will use only first query. thankx.